# Cookies using App Engine and Restlets

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, cookies, restlet, session-cookies

I would like to store an authentication token in a session cookie.  I'm using google app engine and restlets.  I've done a few searches, but I have no idea even where to begin.

I would like to:

- Store the token in a cookie
- Read the cookie when the client makes a request through restlet

Also, is the session cookie the correct place to this type of information?

Comment: What exactly is your question?  If you are using java, it has built-in support for sessions.  Which authentication mechanism are you using, or are you using your own?

Comment: I'm using my own.  I assume the mechanism to set cookies is related to the mechanism that is being used to service requests, in this case restlets.  Is this not correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

restlet does [not](http://www.restlet.org/about/features) have built-in support for servlet like sessions.

You could always try using the restlet [properties](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_1.1/13-restlet/27-restlet/130-restlet.html) for getting cookies, then validate your auth token.  That is assuming your authentication mechanism sets cookies.  Otherwise maybe you could figure something out using restet's [authentication](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_1.1/13-restlet/27-restlet/46-restlet/112-restlet.html) components.

You may also be able to look into [built-in](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#Enabling_Sessions) sessions.